# using multiple BloCs Pattern with rxdart to calculate some values

Tags: bloc, rxdart

I searched the web looking for something to read as an example explaining bloc pattern and streams with rxdart (not the bloc library) and not the counter example or firebase login, an example how to manipulate values from multiple blocs to calculate some other values, but i found almost nothing in this direction. maybe you have an idea, that would be great..

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out my repo (Manually bloc pattern with RxDart) :)) https://github.com/hoc081098/find_room_flutter_BLoC_pattern_RxDart/blob/master/lib/pages/home/home_bloc.dart

Comment: well thanks, but this is huge, i might spend days just to unterstand what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I can simply explain what i meant:
i have multiple blocs, and from multiple TextFields i add a streams to the sink, lets say a scale stream to blocA, and a width stream and a height stream to blocB.
blocA controls and calculate the screen scale
blockB draws a rectangle with the width and height, but its also needs the scale from blocA to show the rectangle in the wright scale.
So how can I handle this. I could also habe blocC That draws a circle and have a Radius stream, that depends on the scale from bocA too.